# Flutter getx doesn't close controller automatically

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am pushing a page with getx controller.

There is an operation, after tapping a button, which awaits for some time and close the page.

But, the controller doesn't get closed automatically. But, if I hot reload it closes the controller.

Interestingly, if I await for 300-350ms the controller gets closed automatically. But, if I await for 500ms etc. it doesn't get closed.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Where did you put the getx controller?

Comment: I am putting in BindingsBuilder when going to the page with Get.to. But, I also tried to put in initState and closeing the controller in the dispose method of the stateful widget.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused of Flutter version.

The app was using 3.10.5 when there was no problem. The problem is happening on 3.16.5. I will research for the problem and edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually close/delete controller from memory.

```
Get.delete<YourController>();
```